# Selective renderscript libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk, native, renderscript

I've been working with renderscript in my project for a while now. In a recent effort to minimize APK size, I started wondering and researching whether the renderscript native libraries (*libRSSupport.so* and *librsjni.so*) - often bundled within the APK, can be omitted for build-targets such as *x86* and *mips*, which are not necessary for release versions of the APK? (note: the libs are added to the APK regardless of the value of *APP_ABI* set within *Application.mk*)

I have come across blogs (much like this one - http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration) seemingly describing how that can be achieved using gradle. But what about projects not using gradle (as my own)? Does anybody know a way -- for example, perhaps an undocumented variable that can be added to the project.properties?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You really cannot remove those libraries, as they are needed for the app to run correctly on other non-ARM devices.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Hines for the attention.

Could you perhaps pour in some more information? AFAIK the Android/Intel market is extremely small (even [Intel's website](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/smartphones/smartphones.html) sports a very short list of mostly outdated smartphones) - especially if your app doesn't support tablets. And, as far as MIPS goes, well they're in an even worse place.

To make a long story short, if APK size matters, I see no reason in keeping x86/MIPS targets.